# MySql table design with variable number of columns

Tags: mysql, database-design

Take a look at this scenario: a parses collects all links on a website and store it in a table. Now, there is no way of knowing in advance how many links there are on a website page, so it is impossible to prepare a table with appropriate number of columns.

```
-------|-------|-------|-------|---------------
website| link1 | link2 | link3 | maybe100columns
```

What is the common way to tackle this problem, when you don't know how many columns you need? Do you encode all the links in json format and store json in 1 column instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to create each column for each link? The relational database system is introduced to tackle these types of problems. A simple solution would be to use two tables for your scenario.

In one table you will keep the `website` column and another column with primary key should be assigned to say `website_id` column.

In your 2nd table there will be primary key assigned to a column say `link_id`, then a foreign key assigned to column `website_id` which will be in the reference of `website_id` of 1st table and finally another column named as say `link`.

So, by this way you will store as many link as required for any site.

Answer (score 3):

the correct way is based on normalization 
instead of

```
-------|-------|-------|-------|---------------
website| link1 | link2 | link3 | mybe100columns
```

you should use  a nornalized  couple of table

master

```
------------|-------
id_website  |website
```

detail

```
---|------------|----
id |id_website  |link
```